# Migrate TFS repo to AzureDevOps repo - missing files from solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have a BI solution with SSAS, SSIS, SSRS and .sqlproj projects stored in a TFS - git repo. I have migrated it from TFS - git repo into a AzureDevOps repo using the Visual Studio 2019 as an intermediary tool. 
Cloned the solution from the TFS repo on my local machine and then push **all the files (entire solution)** to the AzureDevOps repo, but it seems that not all the files were push into the new repo.

Is there a maximum limit of pushing files using VS 2019? 
My solution has a total number of 2.601 files and the size on disk is only 143 MB ...

Comment: Check your .gitignore make sure it's not removing files from your git commit.

Comment: Hello, both of you were rigth. I've excluded the .gitignore file because apparently someone from my team included wanted files there which   led to my ,,missing files'' problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use Visual Studio 2019 as an intermediary tool.

Directly use git command line to handle this in case some files auto ignored by visual studio.

As  *Etienne* commented, also pay attention to your `.gitignore` file, make sure all files you need are committed and pushed to remote Azure DevOps Repo.

You could refer this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/move-git-repos-between-team-projects?view=azure-devops#manually-migrate-the-git-repo-in-five-easy-steps) to manually migrate the Git repo in five easy steps:

- Create an empty Git repo
- Mirror the repository
- Push the repo
- Validate the new repository
- Configure the new repo